# DevExpress XF CollectionView - how to modify tapped cell

Tags: xamarin.forms, devexpress

I am using DevExpress's Free Xamarin controls (they don't provide support) and trying to figure out how I can change something of the selected item cell, eg modify the text in the cell.

```
        <dxcv:DXCollectionView TapCommand="{Binding ItemTapCommand}"  
                           ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
                            DisplayMember="Name"
                            DisplayFormat="Contact: {0}">
    </dxcv:DXCollectionView>
```

And the viewmodel:

```
        public List<Contact> Data { get; set; }

    public ICommand ItemTapCommand => new Command(ItemTapped);
    private void ItemTapped(object obj)
    {

    }

    public CollectionViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
    {
        DevExpress.XamarinForms.CollectionView.Initializer.Init();


        Data = new List<Contact>() {
            new Contact("Nancy Davolio", "(206) 555-9857"),
            new Contact("Andrew Fuller", "(206) 555-9482"),
            new Contact("Janet Leverling", "(206) 555-3412"),
            new Contact("Margaret Peacock", "(206) 555-8122"),
            new Contact("Steven Buchanan", "(71) 555-4848"),
            new Contact("Michael Suyama", "(71) 555-7773"),
            new Contact("Robert King", "(71) 555-5598"),
            new Contact("Laura Callahan", "(206) 555-1189"),
            new Contact("Anne Dodsworth", "(71) 555-4444"),
        };

    }

}


public class Contact
{
    public string Name;
    public string Phone;

    public Contact(string name, string phone)
    {
        Name = name;
        Phone = phone;
    }
}
```

When I set a breakpoint at the ItemTapped, I get the following for the obj, but not necessarily a way to target the cell.

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you don't modify the cell, you modify the data (a Contact) the cell is bound to

Comment: In my particular use case, I want to show an image on that cell while doing some work, and then remove the image once the work is done.

Comment: I have no idea if that is possible.  Generally speaking, trying to muck directly with the visual tree like that is a bad idea

Comment: What I have is a collection of songs displayed, when the user Taps a cell I would play it from the viewmodel - but at the same time I want to change an icon from ‘play’ to ‘stop’

Comment: then bind the icon to some sort of "Status" flag in your model, and update the model to update the UI

Comment: That’s essentially what I’m trying to do, but I still need a cell ID or some way of targeting that particular cell, which is where I’m stuck

Comment: No, you do not.  Place an image control in your template layout and bind it to some property in your model.  Then you can modify that property and the image control will update.  You do not need direct access to the UI to do this.

Comment: xamarin’s standard CollectionView takes an ItemTemplate. In that, you bind to properties of the item (here, the item is Contact). Read Xamarin doc’s for CollectionView. I recommend working with the standard CollectionView, which is well documented, before trying to use a third-party one.